# Docker buildkit `RUN mount=type=cache` unexpected behavior caching ruby bundle install results

Tags: docker, build

I'm trying to use docker's buildkit to cache the results of a bundle install between builds. I'm using the new RUN `mount=type-cache...` option to allow caching the the bunder results for subsequent builds. However, nothing appears to be cached, ever.

I'm using docker 19.03.01 for both docker client and server. I have enabled buildkit on builds vie envar `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1` Note that ssh mounts seem to be working, but not cache mounts. I have these lines in my Dockerfile to run bundler

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental
FROM ruby:2.4.6
ENV BUNDLE_PATH=/bundler
RUN gem install bundle
RUN mkdir /app && mkdir /bundler
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
ENV BUNDLE_PATH=/bundler
RUN mount=type=cache,target=/bundler ls -la /bundler/cache; bundle install
```

The project directory can contain nothing but a Gemfile (called `Gemfile`) with the following contents:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
gem "humanize"
gem "i18n"
gem "rake"
```

I am running the build as follows:

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build . --progress=plain
```

On the first run, the attempt to list `/bundler/cache` fails as expected, and bundler runs. Running the container verifies that everything is installed under /bundler as expected.

However, if the gemfile is changed, running docker build again, results in the exact same output -- the `ls` command fails, and bundler rebuilds the entire gemfile. I would expect the ls command to show me the contents of `/bundler` from the last run, and I would expect the `bundler install` command to only build changed gems.

I can see that a cache is getting created somewhere, as `docker builder prune` does actually prune things after the command is run. But any cache does not seem to be used on subsequent builds.

For example, here is the run stage on the first build with the rake gem removed:

```
#12 [6/6] RUN mount=type=cache,target=/bundler ls -la /bundler/cache; 
bundle...
#12 1.154 ls: cannot access '/bundler/cache': No such file or directory
#12 3.059 Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
#12 3.292 Resolving dependencies...
#12 3.305 Using bundler 1.17.3
#12 3.306 Fetching concurrent-ruby 1.1.5
#12 3.377 Installing concurrent-ruby 1.1.5
#12 3.483 Fetching humanize 2.1.2
#12 3.568 Installing humanize 2.1.2
#12 3.606 Fetching i18n 1.6.0
#12 3.654 Installing i18n 1.6.0
#12 3.691 Bundle complete! 2 Gemfile dependencies, 4 gems now installed.
```

This is as expected. Then when I add the rake gem into the Gemfile, and rebuild:

```
#12 [6/6] RUN mount=type=cache,target=/bundler ls -la /bundler/cache; 
bundle...
#12 1.186 ls: cannot access '/bundler/cache': No such file or directory
#12 3.355 Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
#12 3.562 Resolving dependencies...
#12 3.579 Fetching rake 12.3.3
#12 3.658 Installing rake 12.3.3
#12 3.718 Using bundler 1.17.3
#12 3.719 Fetching concurrent-ruby 1.1.5
#12 3.875 Installing concurrent-ruby 1.1.5
#12 4.029 Fetching humanize 2.1.2
#12 4.068 Installing humanize 2.1.2
#12 4.103 Fetching i18n 1.6.0
#12 4.142 Installing i18n 1.6.0
#12 4.184 Bundle complete! 3 Gemfile dependencies, 5 gems now installed.
#12 4.184 Bundled gems are installed into `/bundler`
#12 4.184 Post-install message from i18n:
```

On this second run I would have expected to see the `ls -la /bundler/cache` to succeed and show me the gems installed on the last run. I would also expect bundler to not fetch and rebuild the gems that were just built.

The idea is that this bunder install just becomes a first stage in the Dockerfile, with the final stage just copying over the contents of the first stages's `/bundler` directory.

I feel like I may be misunderstanding exactly how RUN cache mounts work, but I am mystified as to why this simple example does not seem to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What gemfile? You discuss it but it is no where in your example. See [mcve].

Comment: There's a previous ADD directive that adds it into /app. The gemfile is always present and built -- but the bunder results just don't seem to be cached.

Comment: Please see the "complete" part of the above link.

Comment: The code as edited should be easily reproducible -- thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get this to work with the following changes:

- Add the syntax parser directive at the top (looks like a comment, but it isn't)
- Include the `--` before the mount

The resulting Dockerfile looks like:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental
FROM ruby:2.4.6
ENV BUNDLE_PATH=/bundler
RUN gem install bundle
RUN mkdir /app && mkdir /bundler
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
ENV BUNDLE_PATH=/bundler
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/bundler ls -la /bundler/cache; bundle install
```

Without the `--` before the mount, you were just setting an environment variable in the shell.

---

My build output shows:

```
$ docker build -t test-ruby --progress=plain .

...

#12 [stage-0 6/6] RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/bundler ls -la /bundler/cac...
#12 1.735 total 548
#12 1.735 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Sep 17 20:49 .
#12 1.735 drwxr-xr-x 9 root root   4096 Sep 17 20:49 ..
#12 1.735 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 356352 Sep 17 20:48 concurrent-ruby-1.1.5.gem
#12 1.735 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  60416 Sep 17 20:49 humanize-2.1.2.gem
#12 1.735 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  41984 Sep 17 20:49 i18n-1.6.0.gem
#12 1.735 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  87040 Sep 17 20:48 rake-12.3.3.gem
#12 19.20 Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
#12 19.80 Resolving dependencies...                                            
#12 19.85 Using bundler 1.17.3
#12 19.85 Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.5
#12 19.85 Using humanize 2.1.2
#12 19.85 Using i18n 1.6.0
#12 19.86 Bundle complete! 2 Gemfile dependencies, 4 gems now installed.                           
#12 19.86 Bundled gems are installed into `/bundler`
#12 19.91 total 548                                
#12 19.91 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Sep 17 20:49 .
#12 19.91 drwxr-xr-x 9 root root   4096 Sep 17 21:33 ..
#12 19.91 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 356352 Sep 17 20:48 concurrent-ruby-1.1.5.gem  
#12 19.91 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  60416 Sep 17 20:49 humanize-2.1.2.gem
#12 19.91 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  41984 Sep 17 20:49 i18n-1.6.0.gem
#12 19.91 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  87040 Sep 17 20:48 rake-12.3.3.gem
#12 DONE 20.5s
```

I did include an extra `ls` command after the `bundle install` to debug. Only other reason I can think of for this to not work for you is from cleaning up the build cache which could happen automatically if you build large images and haven't configured your build cache settings.

Comment: Same result -- I actually had the parser directive in the original file -- I just failed to re-add it into the example. Same results, however. I'm wondering if there is some additional setup I've failed to do?

Comment: @MFélixHertz Same result when you built one more time or twice (once to fill the cache?)

Comment: Yes -- I've edited the original question to show the results of the first build, then a subsequent build after adding a gem to the Gemfile. Thanks again

Comment: Whelp, nope -- I'm an idiot or blind. I was seeing --mount where there was only mount. Thanks again -- it's fixed.